# Today who is considered an Am Haaretz?

Tags: history

I understand the question is very general, so any sources discussing an Am Haaretz from around the times of the Achronim to modern day would be very helpful in gaining a clearer picture of what is an Am Haaretz. As always I appreciate any input. Thank You & Be blessed!

Comment: Do you have some technical context in which you think it would have some specific meaning? Consider clarifying.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1268/am-haaretz-gamur-mideoraysa

Comment: I recall (perhaps in the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch) that today we do not consider any run-of-the-mill frum Jew an _am ha'aretz_.

Comment: Regarding my first comment, note that unless we have some specific context for the term, this is just semantics and not answerable.

Answer (score 4):

"Am Haaretz" has different usages

Practically in our times, it is:

1. regarding marriage, it is someone who knows of a Mitzvah and does not keep it (for his own pleasure) (Bais Shmuel [2.20](https://www.sefaria.org/Beit_Shmuel.2.20), Bais Yosef [2.18](https://www.sefaria.org/Beit_Yosef,_Even_HaEzer.2.18), Drisha [2.8](https://www.sefaria.org/Drisha,_Even_HaEzer.2.8), Bach [2.8](https://www.sefaria.org/Bach,_Even_HaEzer.2.8)
   (but the [Tur](https://www.sefaria.org/Tur,_Even_HaEzer.2) says it is someone who is suspected to transgress mitzvos **lihachis** (to anger Hashem))
2. Regarding not marring a daughter of a kohen there is an opinion that an Am Hooretz does not exist (piskai teshuva [2.9](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=eh_x7494)
3. in general, it is someone who does not know Torah (the written Torah) and the  Mishna (the Halochot (H"M [34.17](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Choshen_Mishpat.34.17), Rambam Eidut [11.2](http://www.chabad.org/1178799/) end)
4. also, Someone who is not a comrade ([ḥaver](https://www.sefaria.org/search?q=%E1%B8%A5aver&filters=Talmud&var=1&sort=c)), meaning someone that was not checked if he takes off the proper Trumot and Maasrot, meaning everyone
5. See Berakhot.[47b](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.47b.5-6) and Sotah [22a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sotah.22a.4)
6. It also means normal people (H"M [35.10](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Choshen_Mishpat.35.10) and Rambam [edut 9](http://www.chabad.org/1172777/) halacha 10
7. Someone who can not read, or understand Hebrew (aramaic) when it is read to him (H"M [61.13](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Choshen_Mishpat.61.13) , E"H [66.13](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.66.13) , [142.7](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.142.7) end

Comment: Worth noting that for marriage purposes the Pischei Teshuvah (se'if katan 9 [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14398&st=&pgnum=15)) citing the Chavos Yair says that there is no din of Am Haaretz nowadays.

Comment: @AlterBochur thank you (there is a better link http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=eh_x7494) if you still are without a zivug, you should get yours fast and she should be the correct one and a good one (same for me!)

Comment: thanks for the improved link and the well wishes, I hope Hashem sends you a zivug hagun soon as well. I haven't seen jewishmarriage.us before but it seems to be an entire book that would take a lot of time to go through. From a cursory look, it does seem to be very detailed.

Comment: Supplemental to #6, Rabbeinu Yonah's comment on Pirkei Avot that discusses the 4 midot in people (it's somewhere in 5th chapter, I believe) compares *middat chassid* with *midat am ha'aretz* (re the one who says what's mine is mine and what's yours is yours.) R. Yonah's explanation of *am ha'aretz* there is similar to "the man on the street". Comparing it to middat *chassid* which means someone who goes beyond the halacaha - thus one who says "What's mine is yours and what's yours is yours" is considered a *chassid*. It puts a good perspective on things.

Comment: @DanF https://www.sefaria.org/Rabbeinu_Yonah_on_Pirkei_Avot.5.10.2?lang=bi